# How to Handle class change with beautiful soup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I am just trying to scrape some random news title in a google news page , when i inspect the title of news title i get

`Class = mCBkyc JQe2Ld nDgy9d`

but when i try with Beautifulsoup this class is not present , it changes in content fetched from response

```
Class = BNeawe UPmit AP7Wnd
```

i am aware this might be due to JS but how can i handle it properly

below what i have tried

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

content = requests.get(
    "https://www.google.com/search?q=beautiful+soup+get+text+a&safe=active&rlz=1C1GCEB_enIN960IN960&source=lnms&tbm=nws&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjNzsv-iaTzAhX6yzgGHfeBDzgQ_AUoA3oECAEQBQ&biw=1707&bih=770&dpr=1.13").content

soup = BeautifulSoup(content, features="html.parser")

with open("d.txt", "w") as file:
    file.write(soup.prettify())

for a in soup.find_all('div', class_='BNeawe vvjwJb AP7Wnd'):  # in this line if kept class =  mCBkyc JQe2Ld nDgy9d none is returned 
    print(a)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know what you are actually looking for but:
When you use a selector like:
`div[role='text']`

example:
`soup.select("div[role='text']")`

You will get all news on page:
[image]

As you can see there are 10 items like this on page (all news in my case).
Then you can proceed with rest - finding all needed data in each item.

EDIT:
Unfortunately  you can be blocked  from doing so. Bcoz of this:
[image]

My Advice - use Selenium

Comment: thanks Kozubi i just need to fetch the text of the news title , in my case if you go to thr link & click on inpect on any news title u will get some class name but when triying to find with soup the class is not present int the soup content

Comment: Will be hard bcoz I found that: